# Square Tracing Algorithm not working

Tags: c#, algorithm, loops, unity-game-engine

For some reason I just can't get my square tracing algorith to work, for some reason it's refusing to enter the while loop at all. Here's my code

```
void findEdgeTiles()
{
    List<int> edgeRow = new List<int>();
    List<int> edgeCol = new List<int>();

    int dir = 0;

    //get starting point
    for(row = 0; row < stationWidth-1; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < stationHeight-1; col++)
        {
            if(roomType[row,col] != (int)room.None)
            {
                edgeRow.Add(row);
                edgeCol.Add(col);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(roomType[row,col] != (int)room.None)
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    //north = 0, east = 1, south = 2, west = 3, minus to turn left, plus to turn right
    //turn left
    dir = (dir-1)%4;
    //move left
    row--;

    Debug.Log(row + " != " + edgeRow[0] + " && " +  col + " !=" + edgeCol[0]);
    while(row != edgeRow[0] && col != edgeCol[0])
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered While loop");

        if(roomType[row,col] != (int)room.None)
        {
            //add edge tile
            edgeRow.Add(row);
            edgeCol.Add(col);
            //turn left
            dir = (dir-1)%4;
            //move forward
            if(dir == 0)
            {
                col++;
            }
            if(dir == 1)
            {
                row++;
            }
            if(dir == 2)
            {
                col--;
            }
            if(dir == 3)
            {
                row--;
            }
        }
        if(roomType[row,col] == (int)room.None)
        {
            //turn right
            dir = (dir+1)%4;
            //move forward
            if(dir == 0)
            {
                col++;
            }
            if(dir == 1)
            {
                row++;
            }
            if(dir == 2)
            {
                col--;
            }
            if(dir == 3)
            {
                row--;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < edgeCol.Count; i++)
    {
        roomType[edgeRow[i], edgeCol[i]] = (int)room.Landing;
    }
}
```

[Here's the theory of the algorithm](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/square.html)

The debug logs something like 0 != 1 && 3!=3 showing that the While should evaluate and start looping until you get back to the starting point. What am I doing wrong here? Everything before the while loop is working as expected. I tried `while(row != edgeRow[0] || col != edgeCol[0])` but that just crashed unity, maybe an infinite loop error?

roomType[,] is a 2D int array used for mapping and (int)room.none is an enum

Comment: *The debug logs something like 0 != 1 && 3!=3* hmm, 3 != 3? that is false, so the while should not be executed.

Comment: So it won't execute on a partial false? I thought a partial true would mean it would execute, so should I use the OR operator instead?

Comment: @alwyven there is no such thing as a partial true or false. It id either true or false. It seems that you want OR and not AND

Comment: "partial" booleans? maybe on quantum computers, but in current tech a bit is 1 or 0, true or false XD

Comment: Sorry, I mean partial in that one part of the statement was true and one part false overall evaluated to true, where I was in fact wrong, that's the case in the OR operator I think

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple problems with this that debug helped me to sort out. The while loops should definitely have been an OR operator, and it turned out that modulo didn't quite work the way I thought it did. `(0-1)%4` did not result in `3` as I had expected but instead it resulted in `-1` which was completely useless to me! So instead to turn left I needed to use `dir = (dir+3)%4;' and this got me out of my infinite loop and got me all the out edge tiles as I needed them, I added a and extra condition so corners with no access to the outside didn't end up as edges, here's my working code:

```
void findEdgeTiles()
{
    List<int> edgeRow = new List<int>();
    List<int> edgeCol = new List<int>();

    int dir = 0;

    //get starting point
    for(row = 0; row < stationWidth-1; row++)
    {
        for(col = 0; col < stationHeight-1; col++)
        {
            if(roomType[row,col] != (int)room.None)
            {
                edgeRow.Add(row);
                edgeCol.Add(col);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(roomType[row,col] != (int)room.None)
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    //north = 0, east = 1, south = 2, west = 3, minus to turn left, plus to turn right

    //turn left
    dir = (dir+3)%4;

    //move left
    row--;

    Debug.Log("Moved to: "+ row + "," + col);

    while(row != edgeRow[0] || col != edgeCol[0] || edgeCol.Count == 1)
    {
        //turn left or right
        if(roomType[row,col] != (int)room.None)
        {
            //add edge tile as long as there is space beside it
            if(roomType[row+1,col] ==  (int)room.None || roomType[row,col+1] ==  (int)room.None || roomType[row-1,col] ==  (int)room.None || roomType[row,col-1] ==  (int)room.None)
            {
                edgeRow.Add(row);
                edgeCol.Add(col);
            }

            //turn left
            dir = (dir+3)%4;
        }
        else if(roomType[row,col] == (int)room.None)
        {
            //turn right
            dir = (dir+1)%4;
        }

        //move forward
        moveDirection(ref dir);
    }
}

void moveDirection(ref int dir)
{
    if(dir == 0)
    {
        col++;
    }
    if(dir == 1)
    {
        row++;
    }
    if(dir == 2)
    {
        col--;
    }
    if(dir == 3)
    {
        row--;
    }
}
```

Hope someone finds this useful!